# NSExtension warnings when UIActivityViewController selects AirDrop

Tags: swift

I'm getting the next warning on the Xcode console:

```
[NSExtension] Extension request contains input items but the extension point does not specify a set of allowed payload classes. The extension point's NSExtensionContext subclass must implement `+_allowedItemPayloadClasses`. This must return the set of allowed NSExtensionItem payload classes. In future, this request will fail with an error. Extension: <EXConcreteExtension: 0x283a54cc0> {id = com.apple.Sharing.AirDrop} Items: (
"<NSExtensionItem: 0x280d73a40> - userInfo: {\n    ShowNoContentView = 1;\n}"
```

)

The code I have implemented it's basically a `UIActivityViewController` which receives a CSV document.

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
    
    activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
        (_, _, _, _) in
    }
    
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
        ...,
        ...
    ]

    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.frame
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem

    self.present(activityController, animated: true)
```

The code it's working correctly but I would like to fix that warning. I only have a notification extension, I don't know why it's appearing this warning.

Comment: I get the same message when creating a Siri intent

Comment: Ditto on the creation of Siri Intent.  Also, it only shows up on iOS 15.0.  To me, it looks like they have internally deprecated something internal to a core framework, and something in iOS 15 still uses it.

Comment: This is also happening on macOS 12.1 when using `NSSharingServicePicker`

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Any update? Did you manage to fix the warning?

Comment: @Georg the error just disappeared. Tested on iOS 12 and iOS 15 with Xcode 13.4

Comment: I get this warning and Airdrop does NOT work for me in Xcode 13.4, iOS 15.5 (device, iPhone 7) in a SwiftUI app, using UIViewControllerRepresentable

Comment: Any updates? Do we know exactly what this message means and what is causing this message in common to all the different circumstances it appears?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of **NSExtensionContext** that conforms to the **_allowedItemPayloadClasses** protocol and returns the set of allowed payload classes for your extension.

> Here is an example implementation:

```
class MyExtensionContext: NSExtensionContext {
    override class func _allowedItemPayloadClasses() -> Set<AnyHashable> {
        return [NSURL.self, UIImage.self, NSString.self]
    }
}

let item = NSExtensionItem()
item.attachments = [/* attachments */]
item.setContext(MyExtensionContext())
```

This should resolve the warning and ensure that your extension works correctly with AirDrop.

Comment: I don’t understand this answer. Could you elaborate a little bit? In the original question UIActivityViewController is used, there’s no usage of NSExtensionItem. Where extension item should be injected?